# Receiving webhook in express from local application

Tags: node.js, webhooks

I have an application (headless CMS) running locally. It has an option to send a webhook to another application. I have been trying to interpret this webhook via express using posts. I have not been able to even get it to register a request coming in from the application. I tested this route using postman and found that it is working when I post to it.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Recieved");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send('ok')
});
```

Thus, when I send a post to: http://localhost:3000/recall via postman. I get the following header back:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →X-Requested-With,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →http://localhost:3000
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →2
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Mon, 03 Sep 2018 21:23:22 GMT
ETag →W/"2-eoX0dku9ba8cNUXvu/DyeabcC+s"
X-Powered-By →Express
```

With the body:

```
ok
```

My script also prints the body of the post.

I can verify the webhook is working by testing it with request bin. I get back the following:

```
FORM/POST PARAMETERS
None

HEADERS
Cloudfront-Forwarded-Proto: http
Cloudfront-Is-Mobile-Viewer: false
Cloudfront-Is-Desktop-Viewer: true
Connect-Time: 1
Via: 1.1 3566cbcd49f71967b52a565888e4d272.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 vegur
Content-Length: 387
Connection: close
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Cloudfront-Viewer-Country: US
X-Amz-Cf-Id: dRe5CvkLFJZJNcpZbhmeEHo0ar_taj6guvN8utwkyVXM7ZMJc5BZTw==
Cloudfront-Is-Smarttv-Viewer: false
X-Request-Id: 4b6d2cdc-5c45-495b-b358-2e808e1bfeb4
Cloudfront-Is-Tablet-Viewer: false
Total-Route-Time: 0
Host: requestbin.fullcontact.com

BODY
{"event":"singleton.remove","hook":"Save After Sington","backend":1,"args":[{"name":"Wonder","label":"Wonder","_id":"Wonder5b8cef36a0097","fields":[{"name":"Best","label":"","type":"text","default":"","info":"","group":"","localize":false,"options":[],"width":"1-1","lst":true,"acl":[]}],"template":"","data":null,"_created":1535962934,"_modified":1535962934,"description":"","acl":[]}]}
```

I tried enabling cross-origin requests. How could I fix this problem? My thought is it has something to do with the fact this request is originating and ending locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an application to consume webhooks it needs to have a publicly accessible URL. Basically, the rest of the world (internet) doesn't know your `localhost:3000` endpoints exist.

An easy way to fix this is to use a lightweight tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your local server; in turn allowing other applications to communicate with yours.

You will need to define the specific callback route that you want to consume the webhook POST request. Examples below.

1. Run your node script
2. Turn on ngrok
3. send webhook POST requests to your endpoint using the NGROK https address
   [image: Ngrok example]

Now, instead of sending your webhook to `localhost:8000/MyWebhookConsumingEndpoint`
you send it to
 `https://95e26af4.ngrok.io/MyWebhookConsumingEndpoint`